# How to continue TensorBoardLogger from previous works

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, training-data, pytorch-lightning, checkpoint

I am training my model with percent of data with percent of epoch for example I divide 10000 data in 5 folders with sizes of 2000 data and I divided 100 epoch in 10 epoch for each 2000 data for example in the first session I run model with 2000 data and 10 epoch and the next step I run saved model(with load_from_checkpoint) with other 2000 data in 10 epoch.....
my source for checkpoint and tensorboard_logger and trainer isin below.

```
checkpoint_callback=ModelCheckpoint(dirpath="model",filename="newmodel_2",save_last=True,verbose=True,monitor="val_ce_loss",mode="min")
logger=TensorBoardLogger("training-logs",name="test_2")
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
        max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
        gpus=1,
        max_steps = max_steps,  
        logger=logger,    
    )
```

And my source code for run is

```
base_path_ckpt = '/home/tt/model/last.ckpt'
config_model= model(config, max_steps= max_steps)
model_with_previous = config_model.load_from_checkpoint(base_path_ckpt)
trainer.fit(model_with_previous , datamodule)
```

My question is ,I know how to continue my training model with .load_from_checkpoint but How can I continue showing training_logs with tensorboard?(because when I run again my model for next 10 epoch and 2000 next data I can't see any previous tensorboard_logs)